# How to disable default css in KendoUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

In my application I use global definitions CSS for "INPUT", "SELECT", etc. and when I try use KendoUI widgets, I have problem with formatting - KendoUI widget use my default style CSS.

For example I use:

```
.m-forms SELECT,
.m-forms TEXTAREA,
.m-forms INPUT[type=text] {
...
}
```

I try resolve this problem like that:

```
.m-forms :not([class^="k-widget"]) SELECT,
.m-forms :not([class^="k-widget"]) TEXTAREA,
.m-forms :not([class^="k-widget"]) INPUT[type=text] {
...
}
```

But this not work. How I can disable my default style in KendoUI widget? My example DOM tree like that:
[my page source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlIGY.png)

Answer (score 0):

KendoUI always inject these classes when your application runs. So if you do not like the default color for instance, you can override it with you color. So you create a css file and include it in the page. Just make sure your css file is the after the KendoUI css. After the KendoUI css has run, your css will override KendoUI's css

Then override with your choice, e.g.

```
.m-forms :not([class^="k-widget"]) SELECT,
.m-forms :not([class^="k-widget"]) TEXTAREA,
.m-forms :not([class^="k-widget"]) INPUT[type=text] {

  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```